# Conversion from DXF to SVG

Tags: openlayers-2, maps, svg, map-service, geoconverter

I want to convert a file from DXF to SVG and for that I am writing a python script. However, While converting from DXF to SVG there are certain features that are different such as xOffset, yOffset, scaleFactor etc. How can i find the difference between these files and use this to write the script.

Comment: Do you mean *DFX* or *DXF*?

Comment: oops sorry, DXF*